# Login with Facebook in react native return "The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, facebook, facebook-login

I come to you after hours of research.
I have created my facebook account with the application I am working on and also my firebase account that I have linked through the OAuth redirection URI to the configuration of your Facebook application.
[image]

[image]

But I always get the same mistake. Do you have any leads? Knowing that my APP_ID is the same in the code, on facebook developers and Firebase. And that I redirected the URI of firebase in facebook developpers.
Here is my code :

```
  async function loginWithFacebook(){

    await Facebook.initializeAsync({
      appId      : '1027709424451081'});

    const {type,token} = 
    await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
      permissions:['public_profile'],
    });
    if (type === 'success') {

      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);

      Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then(user => { // All the details about user are in here returned from firebase
        console.log('Logged in successfully', user)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error occurred ', error)
      });

    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the function "signInWithCredentials" you need to pass the auth also which you will get by

```
const auth = getAuth()
```

and then after getting the credentials

```
signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
```

Comment: I try this and i get the same error.

Comment: Did you Add the Hash Key In Your Facebook Account?